# Implementing queue in java

Tags: java, queue

Implementing a queue in Java is pretty common interview question. I surfed online and saw many implementations where they do fancy stuff like implementing queue interface and writing own `addLast()` and `removeFirst()` methods. My question is can't I just use `LinkedList()` class and use its predefined methods `addLast` and `removeFirst` methods to do the same??
    e.g.

```
LinkedList<Student> qu=new LinkedList<Student>();
qu.add(new Student("anadkat1"));
qu.add(new Student("anadkat2"));
qu.add(new Student("anadkat5"));
System.err.println(qu);
qu.removeFirst();
System.err.println(qu);
```

This is giving me the perfect result. Isn't this enough?

Comment: LinkedList implements Queue already, so you're not implementing a Queue, you are simply using it.

Comment: As it's an interview question, the aim is for the interviewer to see if you can code some basic datastructures yourself. It gives us insight into how you write, what style you use, how you approach the problem,etc.

Comment: okay totally got your point. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Queue<T>{
private LinkedList<T> list=new LinkedList<>();

public void insert(T element){
     list.addLast(element);
}

public void remove(){
    list.removeFirst();
}

public int size(){
    return list.size();
}

public T element(){
     return list.getFirst();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have very recently gone through these kind of interview questions.

Using set methods to add,remove, chekForEmpty etc from a list is a general way to implement a queue.

for example :

```
   public void enqueue(E item) {
     list.addLast(item);
     }

   public E dequeue() {
      return list.poll();
      }

   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !list.isEmpty();
      }

   public int size() {
      return list.size();
      }

   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> l) {
      while (l.hasItems())
        list.addLast(l.dequeue());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to maintain an array of items `q` and two indices to the head and the tail of the queue (initially set to 0). Pseudo-code follows:

```
enqueue(x)
{   q[tail++] = x;
}

dequeue()
{   return q[head++];
}
```

If the array overflows, you double the size and reinsert the items. This yields O(1) amortized time per operation. Another approach is to use a linked list (which you should implement) and again store a pointer to the head and a pointer to the tail.